Access E-Mails of Inactive Accounts in Mail
Before macOS Ventura, it was possible to still access the e-mails of inactive accounts in Mail by simply turning then on in the settings. Back then, the accounts were checked after that, and eventually there was an error message. Now however, the check happens immediately and, as a consequence, it is not possible to activate them anymore. I have a lot of inactive e-mail accounts (living the academia lifestyle) and every now and then, I want/need to look something up. Are there any easy solutions for this problem?

Assuming for a moment that the contents of the account are actually downloaded to the local Mac, what happens if you remove network access from the Mac, make it standalone, then turn the account back on?

The e-mails are downloaded to some hidden folders (I made a copy of them, however they are hard to browse without a nice user interface). If I turn off the internet on my mac, I still cannot activate an inactive account, as it is not possible for the mac to verify that account.

I wondered if it would just not try, if it didn't have a network connection.

No, it refuses to switch on the account immediately, but thanks!
